# MongoDB Realm all users automatically loggingout after deployment

Tags: mongodb, realm

I am using MongoDB Realm for authentication in my Rest API writen in node js.

When I do the deployment that Realm authorization token getting expired for all the users. My assumption is  MongoDb Realm is creating temp files inside the application directory and using that for authorization. Users are getting logged out because of this files are getting deleted during the deployment.

If anyone has some idea please help me out

Are this temporary files needed?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and will be difficult to answer. What does 'do the deployment' entail in your use case? Why are the files getting deleted? How are using getting an auth token in the first place? User metadata is read only and sync's from the server - I don't believe those files are directly used for authentication.

Comment: Hi, @Jay thanks for responding to my question. I just want to inform you that  I got a reply from one MongoDB employee. This is what they are saying

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-realm-all-users-automatically-loggingout-after-deployment/188710

Comment: Interesting. So they don't contain any authentication data but do contain some 'user data' (that's vague). Still though the question remains, why are those files being deleted during deployment?

Comment: Hi @Jay
I will explain the deployment process we follow.

Each time we make changes in the source code, During the deployment, we create a new docker image. This new image gets deployed in AWS EC2. Even if we are doing the source code change in a single file. The new docker image will replace the old docker image.
(We are following 
this method from the beginning of this project)

So my assumption is the temporary files associated with old docker images get lost during the deployment process. So all the users are getting logout